# How to synchronize Desktop and Ipad resolution in Css

Tags: html, ios, css, wordpress, ipad

I need to synchronize the resolution between Desktop and Ipad. If I change the value to render the image better for Ipad the image gets skewered on Desktop. How can I separate the resolution between Desktop and Ipad?

Please help me.

```
@media (max-width: 1920px) {
  .photos .infoHover p {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .infoHover {
    padding: 40% 10px 20px 20px;
  }
  .box-emergent {
    left: 39.090%;
  }
  .box-emergent-right {
    right: 39.090%;
  }
}
```

Comment: look into using additional media queries to target ipads.  Specifically combinations of `min-width`, `max-width` and `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio`.

Comment: How I join the code there? Sorry am a newbie!

Comment: There are tons of examples online on how to do this.  Look it up, give it a shot, if you can't figure it out still, come back and show us what you tried.